# Is someone doing negative SEO for my website?

Tags: seo, search-results, ranking, google-analytics-spam, spamming

We are getting too many clicks and links from some junk websites, most of the websites are expired domain when we try to visit it.

We have got these list of domains from using our web master tools and Google Analytics.

INFO: These domains are blocked by Google for malware.

We get too many links and clicks from the following domains.  So, We are thinking that, someone is doing negative SEO for us or want to demage our website.

Since these visits, Our ranking position is dropped.

Can someone help me ?

```
cheapdedicatedhostingcornwall.xyz   
sharedhostingclwyd.xyz  
makemoneywithresellerhostingcastlereagh.xyz 
bestpriceforvpshostingdiscount.xyz  
affordableresellerhostinggrampian.xyz
cheapdedicatedhostingarmagh.xyz 
sharedhostingdiscountcarrickfergus.xyz
vpshostingdiscountcentral.xyz
vpshostingbackupcambridgeshire.xyz
webhostsfreeuk.xyz
allaboutsharedhostingards.xyz
sharedhostingcambridgeshire.xyz
affordablededicatedhostingalderney.xyz
findsystemissueonline.xyz
networkissuereportinfo.xyz
learnsystemlogs.xyz
foundsystemerrorlogs.xyz
checksystemalertsonline.xyz
systemnetworkreports.xyz
erashows.xyz
anysearchhere.xyz
financeholowin.xyz
away-network-alert.xyz
system-critical-alert.xyz
browser-error-alert.xyz
energyholo.xyz
secondclassbooking.xyz
systemcheckinfo.xyz
```

Comment: Also see https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55958/how-to-prevent-negative-seo

Comment: Also see https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/disavow-links-main?pli=1 on how to disavow those links.

Comment: If these sites were infected, then they are simply linking to your site which at least had an attack on it. These types of attacks simply link between infected servers. If your server is not infected, then count yourself blessed. It is common for infected sites to create links to sites where an attack failed in the normal process of the infection. This is script kiddie stuff. This is NOT negative SEO stuff. Just hacker stuff and should clear up after a while.