# Can a website harm the SEO of another?

Tags: seo, spam, negative-seo, malicious

Sounds strange because and indeed it is. I came here to ask for this because I am lost for words, in a negative way. The company I work for, created a new brand name. Let's call the company Foo and the brand name Bar for the example.
So I searched for Bar in Google and obviously, the results were related to Bar and Foo. So far so good. 
What made me scratch my head, was that there were weird results. My company sells cosmetics. We got some results for Bar that were related to:

leather waller
snickers
how to find a specific cemetery (??)
cell phone screen covers
some kinky stuff

Most of the results are like randomurl.tk
Some of them didn't exist at that moment.
Some others, when I entered, I faced a site that was a bunch of links, with really irrelevant stuff.
Some of these came as result showing Foo, others Bar, others Foo Bar.
Title, Meta description keywords are totally unrelated.
It really looks like a bot that gathers random data along with spam links.

The weirdest part is that some of the urls are the website along with a path that was the **exact permalink** of the product in our webpage, with a wishlist in the end if I recall right.

**So here comes the question:**
What on earth is this?
I suspect that this is a sabbotage attempt since it is really targetted and also follows the exact opposite rules of good SEO. I might be paranoid eventually, but hey, I have to ask. 
If someone wants to sabbotage the SEO a webpage, or a brand name, relating the keyword with spam, does Google fall for it? I mean, there is a legit page, with great content, SEO optimized, seen results for some stuff, but when it comes to the cosmetics, it's like we do not exist. Does google relate the website as spam due to other websites that use maliciously the keywords of the company name and brand? 
If so, what do you suggest us to do?

Comment: Harming the SEO of another website is called "Negative SEO".   There are a ton of articles on the subject.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know what to search for. Will take a look. Still how can I fight it?

Comment: See [How to prevent negative SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55958/how-to-prevent-negative-seo)

Comment: Just to save some time to people that might read this question, Disavow backlinks is a great solution that helps google determine wether a site should be related with you or not.