# How can we prevent sites from loading our site in an iFrame which causes spammy links in out "top linking sites" report?

Tags: seo, backlinks, negative-seo, disavow-links

There are few websites which are loading our entire website in iFrame and generating lots of spammy links to our website from their domain. Check [this](http://lilipot.ir/detail/1127030/Yamaha+FZ+V+2.0+Price%2C+Images%2C+Colours%2C+Mileage+%26amp%3B+Reviews+) link which has linked our pages and loaded our website on their domain through iFrame.

We have tried disavowing it multiple times but it still appears as Top linking sites in our google webmasters. Also, reached to owner of website but got no response.

What can we do to:

1. Stop this domain to load our content in iFrame - I am trying this [frame killer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800271/how-to-prevent-my-site-page-from-being-loaded-into-other-website-iframe) script solution. Is this fine?
2. Remove this as top linking sites - Tried to disavow multiple times but it's still top linking.
3. Ensure we do not get any SEO penalty for this - How can we ensure this?

[image: Webmasters snaphot - Top linking Website]

Comment: See also: [How to prevent negative SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55958/how-to-prevent-negative-seo)

Answer (score 1):

Use `X-Frame-Options` headers in your server configuraion file (example .htaccess on Apache):

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think of is to add a base tag in your page `<head></head>`. It's stright up HMTL, but it will work and the pages framing you cannot edit it out and still link to your page. Basically it works like this:

```
<head>
  <title>...</title>
  <base target="_top">
  ...
</head>
```

There are an assortment of values that can be used, however, `_top` will force the page to load as you intended, without being trapped inside someone else's frame/iframe. `_blank` is another option as it will open a new tab/window, also preventing the page from loading in their iframes.

It's been around for years, is widely supported, and it works.
[HTML  target Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_target.asp)